# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities - MVC / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am changing my Linq-to-Sql application to EF 6.1, generate the ViewData using:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetOhaTypes ()
        {
        return (from type in db.OhaType
                where type.Disabled == false
                orderby type.Name
                select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(type.OhaTypeId, type.Name));
        }
```

In Controller:

```
ViewData["OhaTypes"] = _vRepository.GetOhaTypes();
```

In the View:
@functions{

```
    List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownListItems (string listName, int currentValue)
        {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var pairs = this.ViewData[listName] as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>;

        if (pairs != null)
            {
            list.AddRange(pairs.Select(pair => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = pair.Value,
                Value = pair.Key.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Selected = pair.Key == currentValue
            }));
            }
        return list;
        }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I'd suggest showing what you found when searching for that error text and showing the definition of your `OhaType` (or whatever the relevant class is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says only parameterless constructors or initializers are allowed in the query, so you should change your LINQ query.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetOhaTypes ()
{
    return (from type in db.OhaType
        where type.Disabled == false
        orderby type.Name
        select new {Key = type.OhaTypeId, Name = type.Name}).ToList()
        .Select(type => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(type.Key, type.Name));
}
```

We are executing the query first here and on.y after that we're building your KeyValuePairs. An alternative approach is to use a Dictionary (via `ToDictionary` LINQ method) and return this Dictionary to a calling function

Comment: Thank you so much Vsevolod. I just changed the last line to:
.Select(type => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(type.Key, type.Name));
Works great.

Comment: @hncl yep, it's so easy to slip typos late in the evening :) You're welcome!

Comment: This helped me: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/17301972/projecting-into-keyvaluepair-via-ef---linq