# Fetch data by upcoming birthdays in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to show list of people whose birthdays are in coming 15 days. I have below dates in my table column:

**LET ME MORE CLEAR MY QUESTION**

BELOW IS MY EMPLOYEE TABLE COLUMNS

```
EMP_ID  |EMP_TYPE   |EMP_USERNAME       |EMP_DOB
======= |========== |===============    |==================
1       |ADMIN      |ELENA GILBERT      |1993-02-19
2       |EMPLOYEE   |KATHERINE PIERCE   |1993-03-19
3       |EMPLOYEE   |STEFAN SALVATORE   |1993-04-19
4       |EMPLOYEE   |DAMON SALVATORE    |1993-05-19
5       |EMPLOYEE   |JEREMY GILBERT     |1993-05-20
```

Now I just want to show upcoming birthdays in 15 days.
Below I created a custom class in which I set two properties:

```
public class Birthday
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my web method which return me a list from which I want just Emp_Username and Emp_DOB which upcoming within 15 days.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Birthday> getBirthday()
{
   var slist = new List<Birthday>();
   var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
   var query = (from emp in db.Employees
   let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,
                      emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day) -                                                                                                         DateTime.Now).TotalDays where BirthdayDiff >= 0 && BirthdayDiff <= 15
                      select new Birthday { Name = emp.EMP_USERNAME, date = Convert.ToDateTime(emp.EMP_DOB) });
                      return slist.ToList();
    }
```

**Problem** is my above code is not working and not showing any errors in de-bugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using below query I found a way to know upcoming birthdays. I don't know why folks down voted my this post.

```
var day = DateTime.Now.Day;
var month = DateTime.Now.Month;
            var query = (from emp in db.Employees
                     where emp.EMP_DOB.HasValue == true
                     && emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day >= day && emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month == month
                     select new Birthday
                     {
                         Name = emp.EMP_USERNAME,
                         date = emp.EMP_DOB.Value
                     }).ToList();

        return query;
```

Comment: No, it does not seem to be correct. :( emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day >= day && emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month == month this can only compare the current month, cannot get employee with next month's birthday but having day of month less than the current day. I suggest you to give more birthday samples to see whether your algorithm works or not, and take it slowly, one by one...

Comment: I just want to show coming birthdays in 15 days in current month so If I code: emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day <= 15 && emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month == month then I get bdays coming in 15 days.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your query to something like this and then return it:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Employee> getBirthday()
{
    var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
    const int dateOffset = 15;

    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(dateOffset);

    return (from emp in db.Employees
            where emp.EMP_DOB.Value >= today
            where emp.EMP_DOB.Value <= maxDate
            select emp).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why people down voted your answer and my post. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least *three* issues in your code.

---

Firstly, this line can potentially produce incorrect results:

```
let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
```

Note that you use the *current time* to produce *year*

```
DateTime.Now.Year
```

And consider the following case:

> Now is `25-Dec-15` and One of your `Employee` is having birthday in
>   `3-Jan-16`. According to the calculation, you would produce `DateTime`
>   with value of `3-Jan-15` for your `Employee` and you minus it with
>   `DateTime.Now` and thus you will get value < -300 in total days.

---

Secondly, don't use `DateTime.Now` more than *once* in a single query, because the result of the subsequent `DateTime.Now` may be different from the first one. Use only once:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now; //and then just use now
```

Or even better, to remove all hours and minutes discrepancy:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

---

And lastly, you never return the result of the query, but only an empty List.

Note that you define:

```
var slist = new List<Employee>();
```

And the query:

```
var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
var query = from emp in db.Employees
            let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
            where BirthdayDiff >= 0 && BirthdayDiff <= 15
            select emp;
```

But you neither relate your `slist` with `query` nor return the `query` itself. Thus, you always get nothing, because `slist` is always an empty, `new List`.

---

**Minor Edit:** change from `db` to `db.Employees` and adding `ToList()`

Correct three of them and you have a safe way to do get what you want *(Note: beware of leap year)*:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Employee> getBirthday()
{
    var slist = new List<Employee>();
    var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
    var today = DateTime.Today; //2.
    return (from emp in db.Employees
            let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(today.Year, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day) - today).TotalDays
            let TrueBirthdayDiff = BirthdayDiff >= 0 ? BirthdayDiff : BirthdayDiff + 365 + Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.IsLeapYear(now.Year)) //1, 3 and leap year
            where TrueBirthdayDiff >= 0 && TrueBirthdayDiff <= 15
            select emp).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It shows me an error of `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan where is it returned? which line? Oh, sorry, please put `db.Employees` instead of `db` will update my code soon.

Comment: Yes I updated from my end but It shows me above error at return

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan sorry, forgot to add `.ToList()`, since the return is `IEnumerable` otherwise.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan as for the error, there could be some reference to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177561/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti , https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49a23b65-cdf8-4f58-b4a0-4effbe10c1ae/linq-to-entites-parameterless-constructor-error?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan they basically say that you need to re-construct your `Employee` object *after* the query. As I am not sure how your `Employee` object look like, I cannot help much on this. But seeing the example from the links I posted in the comment, you can notice that first you create a kind of `new {prop1 = something, prop2 = somethingElse}` and so on for your query, and then assign them later to your newly made `Employee` object `x => new Employee(prop1 = x.prop1, prop2 = x.prop2)` and so on...

Comment: Please see my updated code. What I want and what I try.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan is that all your code? It looks quite strange to me. For instance, why there is `- select new ...`? It is *minus* and then `select new`? Also, check the first and second issue I mentioned. Seems like you may still have them, no? That is because you use current year...

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan nevertheless, your question is much clearer now. I might be able to help further. Now, in my time zone, it is already past midnight. I need to go to sleep soon. Will try to see the question again tomorrow, if by that time there isn't any good answer yet.

Comment: Fine. You take your time. we discuss on tomorrow.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan "the code isn't working" - this is going to be the first clue, but probably it is best to also display *how* it is not working. Giving three more things will be useful: (1) input (this you already did) (2) expected output (given the input), and (3) actual output. Now, you are missing (2) and (3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103926/discussion-between-ahmer-ali-ahsan-and-ian).

Comment: Please check my answer in below post. I got upcoming birthdays which are coming in current month and also check between in custom days.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an empty list...

```
[WebMethod]
public static IList<Employee> getBirthday()  //<-- changed signature to IList
{
    var slist = new List<Employee>();
    var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
    var query = from emp in db.Employees
                let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,     
                emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Month, emp.EMP_DOB.Value.Day) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
                where BirthdayDiff >= 0 && BirthdayDiff <= 15
                select emp;
    //return slist;  //<-- problem right here!
    return query.ToList();  //<-- this should fix it...!
}
```

If your heart and soul is really tied to that `List<T>`, then do this right before the `return slist`:

```
slist.AddRange(query);
```

HTH!

Comment: It shows me an error of `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: Did you try the `slist.AddRange()` approach?

Comment: Please check my updated question I think its more clear then previous one

Comment: Are you getting this error when you try to compile? If so, have you changed something else, not mentioned in the current question? Also, which line of code is the error associated with? As it stands, the error that you are describing isn't enough information.

Comment: The error shows at the same line of query. Why you down voted my post.